# How to Resolve Nuxt3 Routing Jump with Warnings

Tags: nuxtjs3

[nuxt] Calling `useRoute` within middleware may lead to misleading results. Instead, use the (to, from) arguments passed to the middleware to access the new and old routes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAg3v.png)

I don't know how to solve it